# Rspec No route matches in controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a route:

```
scope '/account' do
  get '/' => 'accounts#index', as: :account
end
```

And I want to test it with RSpec:

```
describe AccountsController, type: :controller do
  it 'renders the index template' do
    get :index
    expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    expect(response).to render_template :index
  end
end
```

But I have got:

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches

How to fix it?

The full trace:

```
[11] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::AccountsController>)> get :index
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"accounts"}
from /home/rubydev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:46:in `generate'
```

Comment: please share error track trace?

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy updated

Comment: Can you provide the whole test file, I've tested your code and it works, which Rails, Ruby and RSpec version?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it to work by changing routes to:

```
 scope '/accounts' do
   get '/' => 'accounts#index', as: :account
 end
```

Im curious though, if `Account` is a resource, why wouldn't you declare an accounts as a resource:

```
 resource :accounts, :only => [:show, :index]
```

Comment: Did you try using `'/accounts'` in scope?

Comment: why i should try it?

Comment: I think You need get :index, scope: '/accounts' . But like @moyinho20 suggested You should use instead Resources. And instead of asking 'why i should try it? ' ...You should instead think of the cons/pros for each suggestion. And instead of saying 'i just support it' ...maybe You should try and improve the code. If someone for your team wrote code that is hard to maintain instead of leaving it like that You should always try and improve the code because even If You ignore it now chances are that You will have to come Back to same line again in the future.

Comment: @Sts because it might work? 
Else I'm not sure what exactly do you want to fix. I can't think of any improvement to my answer. 
Thanks!